# Is EpiServer7 Windows Workflow Deprecated?

Tags: workflow-foundation, episerver-7

I am looking to develop a custom workflow for EpiServer 7, however when looking at the documentation [resources](http://sdkbeta.episerver.com/SDK-html-Container/?path=/SdkDocuments/CMS/7/Knowledge%20Base/Developer%20Guide/Workflows/workflows.htm&vppRoot=/SdkDocuments//CMS/7/Knowledge%20Base/Developer%20Guide/) it is stated that "This feature is only supported in Legacy mode in EPiServer 7." 
I couldn't find why or towards what is EpiServer targeting to migrate. 
Is there any resource about a new "more recommended" approach to customize the publishing workflow for EpiServer 7?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that statement means that workflow support was limited in the new Edit UI in EPiServer 7.0 CMS.
However, it is supported in EPiServer 7.1 Edit UI. Please take a look at the [Release notes](http://world.episerver.com/Documentation/Items/Release-Notes/EPiServer-CMS/EPiServer-7/Release-Notes--EPiServer-7-1-CMS/#workflows).